Prove that this object is always between 1/2 and 1
In particle physics we like to define the thrust as:
$$ T = \max_{\hat{n}} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\textbf{P}_i \cdot \hat{n}|}{ \sum_{i=1}^{N}|\textbf{P}_i|}  $$
where $ \hat{n} $ is a vector and we have N generic 3 dimensional vectors $\textbf{P}_i$. It's trivial to prove that this object is always smaller than 1 using that $ | \textbf{P}_i \cdot \hat{n}| \leq |\textbf{P}_i| $. We get the value  $ \frac{1}{2} $ when those vectors are uniformly distributed spherically, hence we replace that sum with an integral and we are free to allign $ \hat{n} $ wherever we wish. But why is this value the mimimum of this expression?

There must be more to this problem, because if $N=1$ then $T=1$ always. I suspect that you might get a better response on PSE https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76787/22581

I can prove that $T\geq\frac1N$, if I'm not mistaken, but I think I might be able to make it somewhat better. However, I haven't found any physics material stating $\frac12$ as a lower-bound, but I'm not good navigating physics texts, so it could be an oversight. Could you provide a resource that states that $\frac12$ really is a lower-bound?
